# Values from database doesn't display using codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new using codeigniter.
I'm trying to display items from my database, but  I don't know why it doesn't work.
Could you help me, please?

My Controller

```
function Usuario extends CI_Controller{
    function construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('usuario_m');
    }
    public function modificar_usuario(){
        $id_usuario = 1;
        $this->load->model('usuario_m');
        $data['resultado'] = $this->usuario_m->ver_datos_usuario($id_usuario);
        $this->load->view('paginas/modificar_usuario',$data);

    }
```

This is my Model:

```
public function ver_datos_usuario($id_usuario)
{

    $this->db->select('nombre','apellido','nro_ci', 'direccion','email','telefono','password');
    $this->db->where('id_usuario', $id_usuario);
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $resultado = $query->result();

}
```

And this is my view: (Edited)

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
foreach ($data as $d){?>
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $d->nombre;?>" />
<?php } ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `foreach ($data $d)` that alone should be throwing you an error. You need to do `foreach ($data as $d)` you forgot the `as`.

Comment: someone posted an answer based on your original post and you stealth edited the question without marking it as an edit that you made a mistake.

Comment: How can I mark as edited? I'm still having problems. I was typing that part of the code and I forgot to put the "as" in the foreach. But I just wanna say that I'm still having error.

Comment: Simple: you add the new code under your original post and write: *"Sorry, I made a mistake..."*

Comment: Ok. Now it says that Is edited. Thanks. But It stills doesn't show values from database.

Comment: You will need to ask the person who provided you with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
foreach ($data as $d){?>
```

as following

```
foreach($resultado as $d){?>
```

because you are sending `resultado` to view in `$data` array so now `$resultado` can be access as returned result from model

## One more suggestion

Instead return result like `return $resultado = $query->result();` use this `return $query->result();`

Comment: the OP made a stealth edit; look again. Btw, that is not my downvote here and you didn't deserve that because of her mistake. Edit: now that person retracted their dv.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes edit checked, still my answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.Read docs which is about codeigniter result's format.here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html.

So that you can also achieve like this...

In **view**:

```
foreach ($resultado as $d){?>
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $d['nombre'];?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

In **model**:

Change return `$resultado = $query->result();` to `return $query->result_array();`

Notes:

1.`result_array()` returns result in array format.

2.`result()` returns result in object format.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using $data in the foreach iteration use $resultado. Cheers